I encountered an issue while using parallel and nohup simultaneously: cannot open /dev/tty: No such device or address
I have a time-consuming task, so I use parallel to parallelize my script.
my run.sh :
parallel --no-notice \
         --verbose    \
         --progress    \
          -j 4          \
         --ungroup './scripts/chain_base.sh {1} {2} {3}' \
         ::: 150 200 ::: 100 200 500 1000 ::: default v1 < /dev/null

my chain_base.sh like this :
TOKEN_NUM=$1
NUM_ITER=$2
INIT_METHOD=$3

# Reset the SECONDS variable
SECONDS=0
k="5"

for s in $(eval echo "{0..$((k-1))}"); do
python src/abc.py           \
   --num_iter ${NUM_ITER}    \
   --do_kmeans --k $k         \
   --kmeans_split $s           \
   --init_method ${INIT_METHOD} \
   --num_tokens ${TOKEN_NUM}     \
 done

# Print the end time and execution time
echo "End time: `date`"
echo "Execution time: $SECONDS seconds."

Start using script :
nohup bash scripts/run.sh > run.out &

The current information is.

The chain_base.sh can be executed successfully and will not attempt to read any content from the terminal.
The Python program takes a long time to execute, approximately 40 minutes.
The program always encounters the error message "sh: 1: cannot open /dev/tty: No such device or address"
Encountered the following printed logs:

parallel:  SIGHUP received. No new jobs will be started.
parallel:  Waiting for these 4 jobs to finish. Send SIGTERM to stop now.
parallel:  ./scripts/chain_base.sh 150 200 default
parallel:  ./scripts/chain_base.sh 150 500 default
parallel:  ./scripts/chain_base.sh 150 500 v1
parallel:  ./scripts/chain_base.sh 150 200 v1


The program can run up to 4 processes in parallel, but some processes may encounter the error "sh: 1: cannot open /dev/tty: No such device or address" and stop, while other processes continue until all 4 processes encounter this error. When the program completely stops, it usually executes 8 tasks, which are the variables {1} in parallel attempting to switch.

Add --no-notice to parallel command
Result: Useless

Add < /dev/null to parallel command
Result: Useless

Switch to tmux instead of running as a nohup in the background
Result: Introduced new problems, mainly Python environment issues. The terminal started by tmux cannot inherit the source terminal environment, and the conda environment is base, causing the run to fail.



you may want to run those scripts with debug (-x) to get more details especially if its only happening occasionally. also, checkout the -o and/or --tty options and see if they help.
